# Call a function from a class

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, ado.net, ado

I am just getting into using databases. I have created a class that seem to work. I have here a function I created with a tutorial. it is part of a DataAccess.class file. What I am confused about is how to;

A) Include the DataAccess.class file in the form I am working on
and 
B)Call the Insert Function with a Button

Here is the code

```
Public Shared Function InsertNewRecord(ByVal item1 As String, ByVal item2 As String, ByVal item3 As String) As Boolean
'Create the objects we need to insert a new record
Dim cnInsert As New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString("YourConnName"))
Dim cmdInsert As New OleDbCommand
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO YourTable(column1,column2,column3)     VALUES(@item1,@item2,@item3)"
Dim iSqlStatus As Integer

'Clear any parameters
cmdInsert.Parameters.Clear()
Try
   'Set the OleDbCommand Object Properties
   With cmdInsert
      'Tell it what to execute
      .CommandText = query 
      'Tell it its a text query
      .CommandType = CommandType.Text 
      'Now add the parameters to our query
      'NOTE: Replace @value1.... with your parameter names in your query
      'and add all your parameters in this fashion
      .Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", item1)
      .Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", item2)
      .Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", item3)
      'Set the connection of the object
      .Connection = cnInsert
  End With

  'Now take care of the connection
  HandleConnection(cnInsert)

  'Set the iSqlStatus to the ExecuteNonQuery 
  'status of the insert (0 = failed, 1 = success)
  iSqlStatus = cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery

  'Now check the status
  If Not iSqlStatus = 0 Then
      'DO your failed messaging here
      Return False
  Else
     'Do your success work here
      Return True
  End If
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.Message, "Error")
Finally
    'Now close the connection
    HandleConnection(cnInsert)
End Try
End Function
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
Yes, It says its not declared
```

To use a public shared function written in other class you could do one of these things:

1. Just import your Class into the class where you are trying to call the function and try again.

   ```
   Imports NameOfYourClass
   ```
2. If you didn't imported your secondary class into your main class then you need to specify the name of your secondary class before the function name.

   ```
   Public class Form1

   Private Sub Test()

       ' Call a function from other Class.
       NameOfYourClass.InsertNewRecord

   End Sub

   End Class
   ```

Did this solved your issue?

Answer (score -2):

did you try "call InsertNewRecord" on a button click?

Comment: Yes, It says its not declared

Comment: This kind of answers that really are comments are prohibited in SO rules